# std::zoned_time on Windows Server not working

Tags: c++, windows, c++20, c++-chrono

I've encountered a weird problem with std::chrono::zoned_time{}. Even oddly it works on my machine not the remote sever I'm building this app for.

This simple code - witch I found there [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/zoned-time-class?view=msvc-170#example-get_info)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;

int main()
{
    zoned_time zt("Antarctica/Casey", sys_days{2021y/September/15d}+16h+45min);
    sys_info si = zt.get_info();
    std::cout << si;

    return 0;
}
```

which writes on development machine

```
begin: 2020-10-03 16:01:00, end: 32767-12-31 23:59:59, offset: 39600s, save: 0min, abbrev: GMT+11
```

just dies on the deployment server.

I really don't get what's being wrong here.

Development machine is Windows 10 Pro, version 21H2, build 19044.2130
Deployment server is Windows Server 2016 version 1809, build 17763.3532

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know, but I suspect that your deployment server does not ship with the ICU library that is required for this part of C++20 to work on Windows platforms.

[From here:](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp20s-extensions-to-chrono-available-in-visual-studio-2019-version-16-10/)

> While our current implementation relies on the availability of the ICU DLL in more recent OS versions, we have plans to revisit the issue and investigate implementing a fallback for older operating systems.

Comment: Thank you for answer. So if i could have a follow up question... So the easiest way around for me is to use [date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) library and replace it with the std when Microsoft revisit the [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/1911)?

Comment: I don't know if that is the easiest way or not.  I'm not an experienced Windows developer.  I'm also wondering if installing the ICU library on your deployment machine would work.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the timezone related features are only available in Microsoft STL starting with Windows10 1903. That's why the `zt.get_info()` call fails on the Deployment server.  Same applies to Windows10 LTSC 2019 - both are based on Windows10 1809.

See also: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/3853 which points to some notice inside a microsoft-blog-post regarding "C++20’s Extensions to Chrono in Visual Studio 2019".

Most extensive issue dealing with this problem is https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/1911 open since May 2021. There are also some notes on which DLLs need to be copied to get the functionality working. Downside is that they will no be covered by WindowsUpdate.